# Overlapping Anchor Tags When Hovering Over One

Tags: css

I'm working on solving a CSS display issue and I'm stumped on how to solve this besides simply expanding the width of the parent div.

Here's the layout:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Test Longer 23 Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Test 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

li + li {
  border-width: 0;
}

li {
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  padding: 14px 0;
  list-style: outside none none;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 72px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

This all works fine, except when hovering over the second link (Test Longer 23 Item), which results in the bolded, underlined text wrapping to a second line which overlaps with the anchor tag below it. I could easily fix this by expanding the width of the `div` so that it doesn't wrap, but I'm hoping there's a more dynamic solution available to "push" the subsequent `li` elements down when hovering.

Is this possible in pure CSS?

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/yebujekuco/1/edit)

Comment: You can disable line wrap, but I'd consider instead using different effect than bold, or perhaps giving it more space...

Comment: You're setting the li height. The li is wrapping and causing the overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by adding `display: inline-block;` to `li`.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

li + li {
  border-width: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block; /* <-- this! */
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  padding: 14px 0;
  list-style: outside none none;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 72px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Test Longer 23 Item</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Test 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but when I apply it in my jsbin, Test Longer 23 Item is offset from the others (it is to the left of the other two in terms of horizontal alignment)

Comment: @SvenGrosen It actually works at my end: [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/nuqihajodo/1/edit?html,css,output), here is the [snapshot](http://i.imgur.com/xLYe1HU.png?1). Could you please try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Ah, this might be a browser issue. It works ok in Chrome, but in FF (which I was using initially), it has the offset issue.

Comment: @SvenGrosen To fix that, do `display: inline-block;` instead. Answer updated. So thats a cross-browser solution now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height` for the `li` instead of strict `height` value that will make them overlap:

```
li {
  min-height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Or, if you don't want it to split into 2 lines, just add the proper `white-space` value:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```